# How to get Last Inserted ID if using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using EF to add record. I want to get the last Inserted ID. Following is my Code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO MyTable(PONumber, Status, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, CreatedOn) VALUES(@PO_NUMBER, '0', @STAFF, GETDATE(), GETDATE())";

parameterList = new List<object>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@PO_NUMBER", poNumber));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@STAFF",staff));

parameters = parameterList.ToArray();

result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters);

query = "SELECT NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

var id = db.Lists.SqlQuery(query);
```

How do I iterate record from var `id`?

Comment: If you're using EF - why on earth are you doing an `INSERT` with raw SQL?? The **whole point** of EF is that you can deal with nice **objects** instead of raw SQL! Just create your `MyObject`, set properties, add it to the EF context, call `.SaveChanges()` and there is your `IDENTITY` property set for you! No messing around with SQL needed ..

Comment: @marc_s Been working on asp.net very first time on asp.net and EF. So example I found I tried to implement it based on my need. Can you help me to figure out with example what are you talking about?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using EF, the whole point is that you **don't** have to fiddle around with raw SQL. Instead, you use the object classes generated by EF corresponding to your database tables.

So in your case, I would much rather do something like this:

```
// create the EF context
using(YourEFContext ctx = new YourEFContext())
{
     // create a new "MyTable" class
     MyTable newEntity = new MyTable();

     // set its properties
     newEntity.PoNumber = poNumber;
     newEntity.Status = 0;
     newEntity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
     newEntity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
     newEntity.UpdatedBy = staff;

     // add new entity to EF context
     ctx.MyTable.Add(newEntity);

     // save changes to database
     ctx.SaveChanges();

     // read out your newly set IDENTITY value 
     int newIdentityValue = newEntity.ID;
}
```

Clean object-oriented code - no messy SQL needed **at all!**

Answer (score 0):

What if you needed to insert into a table without triggering validation on the models used to insert into the table? IE in the DB a field is not required and an insert of null would work, but in the EF Model it is a required field?