# How to retrieve last insert id from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I inserted the data into a table using Entity Framework but now I need to retrieve the last id from last executed query.

Here is my code

```
var filedbdata = "'" + FileTitle + "'" + "," +
                 "'" + path + "'" + "," +
                 "'" + Session["UserID"] + "'";

var query = "insert into File_Upload(file_title,file_loc,file_userid) values(" + filedbdata + ")";

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
db.SaveChanges();

int lastid = ??
```

Comment: Why string concatenation if you can use safe sql parameters?

Comment: Not sure on the code exactly, but you should be able to order your data by descending for the id using .OrderByDescending and then select the first item in this list.

Comment: And why are you using EntityFramework if you're building simple SQL queries like that manually anyways? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework for an answer to your questoin, and an example of how to code it. If you want to return the newest ID from your query, add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to it.

Comment: It seems you have Auto Generated ID than just fetch the max(id)

Comment: What exacly `lastid` means? Is it an auto generated id or something?

Comment: Use scope_identity() in sql which will return the last id

Comment: What RDBMS? I don't know if entity framework have some built in property for this, but to get the last auto generated id from the database is dependent on the RDBMS, and also, the phrase "the last auto generated id" itself is ambiguous at best.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava: Bad idea. what if between the insert and select there was another insert from a different source?

Comment: A good way to follow EF; http://stackoverflow.com/a/26053354/2130976

Comment: @MaheshMalpani scope_identity() has it's limitations. for instance, if your target table have an instead of insert trigger, scope_identity() will not give you the correct number.

Comment: if you would actually **USE** Entity Framework, create a new object and save that - EF would give you back the newly inserted `Id` for free - just like that ..... **USE** EF !

Answer (score 3):

If you would be *actually **using*** EF by creating a new object and storing it, you'd get back the new `Id` from EF - for free, just like that!

```
// create new object to insert
FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
fu.file_title = FileTitle;
fu.file_loc = path;
fu.file_userid = Session["UserID"];

// add new object to database context and save it
db.FileUploads.Add(fu);
db.SaveChanges();

// you get back the newly created "ID" FOR FREE!
int lastid = fu.file_id;
```

If you're using Entity Framework - use **EF** and stop doing everything the hard way in "raw", low-level SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) like this:

> **OUTPUT Clause**
>
> Returns inserted rows as part of the insert operation. The results can
>   be returned to the processing application or inserted into a table or
>   table variable for further processing.

```
var query = "insert into File_Upload(file_title,file_loc,file_userid) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID values(" + filedbdata + ")";
```

And to retrieve it you can simply use

```
int id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar
```

Also it would be better to use `parameterized query` instead of using string concatenation. It is a standard practice to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: +1 I liked this idea but I would like you to read [parameterized SQL: Comment by Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848805/getting-value-from-a-database-using-textbox/34848901#comment57437927_34848901)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava:- Added the note to it.